# LoggerFactory To Output To File

Tags: c#, logging, c#-4.0

Currently the application, Logger writes to the console by using the `AddConsole()` method.

How can it be set to write to a file?

---

for example to the directory "c:\workspace\TestProject\Log.txt"

```
logger = new LoggerFactory()
             .AddConsole()
             .CreateLogger("Msg");
```

Comment: What's the logging framework/class you are using?

Comment: This is the MSFT framework logging. and No I dont see any methods exposed for writing to file ..... Actually that was my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you are using `Microsoft.Framework.Logging` 
But out-of-the-box implementations are provided for basic console logging and a few other targets, you’ll need a logging back-end like Serilog or NLog to gain the kind of functionality you're requesting.

I would recommend you to use NLog (just personal preference)

```
Install-Package NLog
```

then add to your code

```
loggerFactory.AddNLog(new global::NLog.LogFactory());
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/samples/SampleApp

http://nlog-project.org/

Comment: I've just run Install-Package NLog and it has failed